# Rust: not able to understand multiple references getting created

Tags: rust

How to resolve the below code which currently not getting compiled due to occurrences of mutable and immutable references in the same scope

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::sync::Mutex;

struct A {
    data_list: Mutex<HashMap<String, String>>,
}

impl A {

    fn new() -> A {
        A {
            data_list: Mutex::new(HashMap::new())
        }
    }
    
    fn find_and_delete(&mut self) {
        let mut id = String::from("");
    
        let data_list_ref = &mut *self.data_list.lock().unwrap();
        for (key, data) in data_list_ref.iter_mut() {
            if data == "abc" {
                id = String::from(key);
    
                break;
            }
        }
    
        if !id.is_empty() {
            let entry = data_list_ref.remove_entry(&id);
            if let Some((_, mut data)) = entry {
                self.del(&mut data);
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    fn del(&mut self, data: &mut String) {
        
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = A::new();
    a.find_and_delete();
}
```

Error

```
warning: unused variable: `data`
  --> src/lib.rs:37:23
   |
37 |     fn del(&mut self, data: &mut String) {
   |                       ^^^^ help: if this is intentional, prefix it with an underscore: `_data`
   |
   = note: `#[warn(unused_variables)]` on by default

error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/lib.rs:31:17
   |
19 |         let data_list_ref = &mut *self.data_list.lock().unwrap();
   |                                   ------------------------------
   |                                   |
   |                                   immutable borrow occurs here
   |                                   a temporary with access to the immutable borrow is created here ...
...
31 |                 self.del(&mut data);
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
...
34 |     }
   |     - ... and the immutable borrow might be used here, when that temporary is dropped and runs the `Drop` code for type `MutexGuard`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0502`.
```

Comment: Inline `del()` into its callsite.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I'm not getting why this code is not getting compiled? can you explain the issue if possible?

Comment: The error message explains it. You can't have a mutable reference at the same time as an immutable reference.

Comment: @Unmitigated I'm not getting why in the line `let data_list_ref = &mut *self.data_list.lock().unwrap();` an immutable reference is getting created?

Comment: `self` is being referenced in that line and that reference is preserved by `data_list_ref` since its lifetime is bound to `self`.

Comment: @kmdreko but it's a `&mut self`, correct?

Comment: `self` is a mutable reference yes, but its borrowed immutably because `self.data_list.lock()` only requires an immutable borrow. However that's irrelevant to solving your problem since multiple mutable references would conflict with each other just the same.

Comment: @kmdreko can you help me out here?